# tkinter call a function every second?

Tags: python, tkinter, time, sleep, updating

I want to call an update function every 1 second to update some stuff. I have tried using a while loop and time.sleep but that does not work. I though that I could attach a function to mainloop so it is called everytime Tk() updates. But I don't know any other way can you help?

```
from tkinter import *

def Update():
    #Stuff

Master = Tk()

Master.mainloop() # Whenever this updates call Update
```

Comment: You need `master.after( 1000, Update )`.

Comment: I have tried that it only does it ones then stops

Comment: Right.  In your function, you have to call `after` again to get another callback.  Tkinter doesn't do repeating timers.

Answer (score 2):

Use `after` to call the `update` function, and have `update` call `after` itself in order to repeat indefinitely

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()


def update():
    # do things
    master.after(1000, update)


master.after(0, update)  # begin updates
master.mainloop()
```