# Python spambot code not working becuse of interaction function and loop

Tags: python, loops, variables, tkinter, pycharm

I am trying to create a spambot that continously spams text I give it. While I managed to do it just with coding (no GUI) I was now trying to create a GUI with tkinker, but it doesn't seem to work. I came to the conclusion (please correct me if I am wrong) that it has to do with the spam variable and the while loop. When I execute the program launches and I can interact with the GUI and everything, but when I press the start nothing happens.

```
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui, time


root = Tk()
root.geometry("240x100")

e = Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

spam = 0

def start_pressed():
    time.sleep(5)
    global spam
    spam = 1





def stop_pressed():
    global spam
    spam = 0



Start = Button(root, text="Start", fg="green", command=start_pressed)
Stop = Button(root, text="Stop", fg="red", command=stop_pressed)

Start.grid(row=1, column=0)
Stop.grid(row=1, column=2)

while spam == 1:
    pyautogui.typewrite(e.get())
    pyautogui.press("enter")


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Once the start button is pressed and the while loop is entered, the UI can no longer be updated by `root.mainloop()`. Try fixing this first.

Comment: edit* I know that the += and -= are uneccesary as I could have just used =, but since that didn't work I was trying something else.

Comment: @Shifu why do you say so, and how could I fix it, I thought that the UI could still be updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `after` method to call a function without disrupting the UI. See ["tkinter call a function every second?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74144890/14160311).

```
spam = 0

def start_pressed():
    time.sleep(5) # wait 5 seconds before chaos
    global spam
    spam = 1      # set flag
    start_spam()  # call "recursive" method

def start_spam():
    global spam
    if spam == 1: # check flag
        pyautogui.typewrite(e.get())
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        root.after(100, start_spam)

def stop_pressed():
    global spam
    spam = 0      # set flag
```

Of course, you can adjust the 100 to a lower number if you want it to be faster.

Comment: Note that `start_spam` isn't a recursive function but kind of acts like one. It schedules a call to itself aster 100 milliseconds (0.1sec)

Comment: Hey man thanks so much this worked, but, since I am new to Python, would you mind explaining (or telling me what to search) why defining start_spam as a function works but just using a normal variable doesn't? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TheLizzard +1 yes hence the quotes. I should have been more explicit.

Comment: @AndreaDiCampo You should look into what `root.mainloop()` actually does. When you click the start button, `start_pressed()` is called in your original code, which sleeps for 5 seconds so the UI cannot update for those 5 seconds, then tkinter continues running afterward and your while loop is never reached.